# Image of open set under the function that maps vectors from Rn to R by selecting the ith component is open

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $A$ be a subset of $R^n$, with $x\in R^{n}$ Consider the projection function $\pi_i:\mathbb{R^n} \to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\pi_i(x)=x_{i}$.
Prove that if $A$ is an open set then $\pi_i(A)$ is open. Something I should mention is that I was asked to prove this using continuous functions

In order to prove this I tried to prove that $\pi_i^{-1}$ is continuous. and that would make the preimage of an open set under $\pi_i^{-1}$ open, taking the preimage of A under $\pi_i^{-1}$ $$(\pi_i^{-1})^{-1}(A)=\pi_i(A)$$ which would make $\pi_i(A)$ open.

I’m struggling with finding the expression of $\pi_i^{-1}$.

is this the right way to prove this?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\pi_i^{-1}$ is not well defined as a function. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have that $\pi_1((1,2)) = 1 = \pi_1((1,1))$, so $\pi_1$ is not injective and hence not invertible.

One can prove the claim directly. Suppose $A$ is open, then for every $x$ we can find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon (x) \subset A$. It follows that for any $x$, the set $\{y \mid | x_i - y | < \varepsilon\} \subset \pi_i(A)$. Hence $\pi_i(A)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose without loss of generality that $i=1$. Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x \in \pi_1(U)$. Then there exists some $y=(x,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in U$ such that $\pi_1(y)=x$. Since $U$ is open, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_n(y,\epsilon) \subset U$. This implies that $y_\delta:=(x+\delta,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in U$ for all $-\epsilon<\delta<\epsilon$, since $d_n(y_\delta,y)=|\delta|$. This gives us that $B_1(x,\epsilon) \subset \pi_1(U)$, hence $\pi_1(U)$ is open.